# Flutter can't change route because undefined name context with PopupMenuButton how to solve?

Tags: mobile, routes, flutter, navigator

I want to click an item menu (PopupMenuItem) and go to another route using Navigator.push but context is undefined inside the method.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  final List<Choice> choices = const <Choice>[
    const Choice(title: 'Settings', icon: Icons.settings),
    const Choice(title: 'Log out', icon: Icons.exit_to_app),
    ];



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'MyTitle';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
          actions: <Widget>[
                PopupMenuButton<Choice>(
                  onSelected: onItemMenuPress,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return choices.map((Choice choice) {
                      return PopupMenuItem<Choice>(
                          value: choice,
                          child: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Icon(
                                choice.icon,
                              ),
                              Container(
                                width: 10.0,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                choice.title,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ));
                    }).toList();
                  },
                ),
              ],
        ),
        body: Text("Hello world")
      ),
    );

  }

    void onItemMenuPress(Choice choice) {   
      if (choice.title == 'Log out') {
        print("Logout");
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LogoutRoute()));
      } 
  }

}

class Choice {
  const Choice({this.title, this.icon});

  final String title;
  final IconData icon;
}

class LogoutRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Logout"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text("Screen"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried to pass a context in onItemMenuPress in this way:

```
void onItemMenuPress(Choice choice, BuildContext context)
```

but:

```
onSelected: onItemMenuPress(context)
```

is not working.

Neither this approach works:

```
onSelected: (Choice c) { Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LogoutRoute())); }
```

I was following this tutorial:
https://medium.com/flutter-community/building-a-chat-app-with-flutter-and-firebase-from-scratch-9eaa7f41782e

and there is a snippet of his code (similar to mine) that seems to work for him:
https://github.com/duytq94/flutter-chat-demo/blob/master/lib/main.dart

I refer to line 235 (onSelected) and lines 199-205 (actual onItemMenuPress method)

How is it possible? How can I salve?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here you have :

```
MyApp    <------ context
  --> MaterialApp
   (--> Navigator built within MaterialApp)
      --> Scaffold
        --> App Bar
          --> ...
```

So when you're using the context to find the Navigator, you're using a context for the MyApp which isn't under the navigator.
so we can either make a new Stateless or Stateful Widget subclass to contain your `Scaffold`, as the build function within those will point at that level instead, or we can use a `Builder` and define the builder callback (which has a context pointing at the Builder) to return the `Scaffold`.

Working Code we created new subclass - `HomeScreen` :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'MyTitle';
    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: HomeScreen(title),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  HomeScreen(this.title);

  final List<Choice> choices = const <Choice>[
    const Choice(title: 'Settings', icon: Icons.settings),
    const Choice(title: 'Log out', icon: Icons.exit_to_app),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
          actions: <Widget>[
            PopupMenuButton<Choice>(
              onSelected: (val) => onItemMenuPress(val, context),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                return choices.map((Choice choice) {
                  return PopupMenuItem<Choice>(
                      value: choice,
                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(
                            choice.icon,
                          ),
                          Container(
                            width: 10.0,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            choice.title,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ));
                }).toList();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: Text("Hello world"));
  }

  void onItemMenuPress(Choice choice, BuildContext context) {
    if (choice.title == 'Log out') {
      print("Logout");
      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LogoutRoute()));
    }
  }
}

class Choice {
  const Choice({this.title, this.icon});

  final String title;
  final IconData icon;
}

class LogoutRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Logout"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text("Screen"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because your flutter SDK and dark SDK is not working properly. you can solve this issues upgrading your flutter sdk. go to the terminal and type

> flutter upgrade --force

after that your fluter sdk and dark sdk will be upgrade, after the installation complete you will be fine.